# How to hook inside a function in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I got a plugin (kind of sign up form), that offers developers some actions/hooks to add their own stuff. Inside the plugin the function is called like this:

```
// Allow devs to hook in
do_action( 'after_record_action', $result, $data, $format );
```

I guess that `$data` is an array storing the form data. After a visitor uses the signup form I want to send a mail containing `$data` using [`wp_mail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/)

How can I execute the following script using `after_record_action`? Do I need to add this inside my `functions.php`?

```
// get data from $data[] array
$data['email'] = $email;
$data['key'] = $key;

// use $data to create a personalized mail
$to = $email;
$subject = "Wordpress Test";
$content = "Hi, this us your key:" . $key . "Enjoy using it!";

// send mail using wp_mail
$status = wp_mail($to, $subject, $content);
```

I appreciate any help in combining these, as I am not too experienced using php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following code into your **currently active** theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_action('after_record_action', 'marian_rick_custom_action', 10, 3);
function marian_rick_custom_action ($result, $data, $format){
// get data from $data[] array
$email = $data['email'];
$key = $data['key'];

// use $data to create a personalized mail
$to = $email;
$subject = "Wordpress Test";
$content = "Hi, this us your key:" . $key . "Enjoy using it!";

// send mail using wp_mail
$status = wp_mail($to, $subject, $content);
}
```

if you are interested, how all this really works, check the official docs [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/)

Comment: Won't the OP need to set the `$accepted_args` parameter of `add_action()` to get all 3 arguments passed in to the `marian_rick_custom_action` function?

Comment: Hey both of you, thanks for the great help :) doesn't seem too hard to accomplish quite a lot of things using action hooks. You just need to understand which part is saved and called at which place. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @TarunMahashwari when I use this code, the `$key` parameter always outputs an empty string. Is there a markup error I have not seen yet?

Comment: @MarianRick i think you should reverse this `$data['key'] = $key;` statement to `$key = $data['key'];` and similarly reverse this `$data['email'] = $email;` statement to `$email = $data['email'];`

Comment: Thanks! I adopted my jQuery knowledge, but the reverse statements do work :) thanks a lot again! Maybe you could update your answer as well, so that it already shows the right markup for others, if you want to :)